# How can I pivot column headers into rows?

Tags: sql-server, pivot, snowflake

I would like to get a list of column headers for a table.

I have queried

```
SELECT TOP 0 * FROM TABLE_NAME.
```

But now I want to pivot those column names into rows. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Using the Stack Overflow database as an example:

```
SELECT TOP (0) * FROM dbo.Users;
```

| Id | AboutMe | Age | CreationDate | DisplayName | DownVotes | EmailHash | LastAccessDate | Location | Reputation | UpVotes | Views | WebsiteUrl | AccountId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

The display you want is available directly from system metadata without pivoting:

```
SELECT 
    C.[name] -- returns the column name
FROM sys.columns AS C
WHERE 
    -- Put your table name inside the OBJECT_ID function here
    -- The 'U' parameter ensures we only match user tables
    C.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Users', 'U')
    -- Don't show any hidden columns
    AND C.is_hidden = 'false'
ORDER BY 
    -- Return columns in left-to-right order
    C.column_id;
```

| name |
| --- |
| Id |
| AboutMe |
| Age |
| CreationDate |
| DisplayName |
| DownVotes |
| EmailHash |
| LastAccessDate |
| Location |
| Reputation |
| UpVotes |
| Views |
| WebsiteUrl |
| AccountId |